# Why is gpg failing when I have installed pinentry?

Tags: macos, gnupg

Despite me installing pinentry, I *still* get the following error:

```
xxxxxxxMacxxxxx:~ MAU$ gpg2 -c --cipher-algo=aes
gpg-agent[89931]: can't connect to the PIN entry module: IPC connect call failed
gpg-agent[89931]: command get_passphrase failed: No pinentry
gpg: problem with the agent: No pinentry
gpg: error creating passphrase: Operation cancelled
gpg: symmetric encryption of `[stdin]' failed: Operation cancelled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually a `gpg-agent.conf` file left over from when I had mac GPG installed. Oh yeah and here's a test of `gpg`'s symmetric encryption function (the password is stackexchange (all lowercase) btw.):

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.20 (Darwin)

jA0ECgMC77crPqRqPGLE0pgB6nSD00hMogXLXJ1V2HlCzkFxbJlB7ZOo1HlsHENJ
xDuccBNqlxvSEqZuege04dehYOfKPe3jQEODaywH2sQS9VNR04Wvjeek9lyGHh0A
sWdiUcW1x884oZG0yOdpLXvY8t+Tzc0tWH0amyZACQ5KsX34L2cNsvbGwDejYp0d
C31gNu4lVAH+4EZe3rnY5YImCZNlQM2/CQ==
=z3bc
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Comment: Decrypts fine here. :) Also, nice to see you're using TWOFISH.

Answer (score 1):

When pinentry dies you need to relaunch it from wherever its launch on start instructions get installed to (I'm pretty sure it's somewhere in /System/Library/, but that doesn't really narrow it down).  It's possible that "kill -HUP $PID" on the process ID of gpg-agent might kick it into gear too.

Alternatively GPG 1.4.x can exist alongside GPG 2.0.x and is usually compiled without gpg-agent.  So it will keep working.  I recommend recompiling from source with the current version, though.  That's how I've avoided all the pain from gpg-agent.

Comment: I assume you think I'm using the precompiled distrib of gpg for mac osx? I'm using a version I compiled myself.

Comment: Excellent. Personally I use my own version of the 1.4.x branch (with all cipher algorithms, larger key sizes and increased secmem). If sticking with the 2.0.x branch you should update to 2.0.22 due to a couple of obscure security issues (unlikely to be an issue on your own hardware, but still).